# How do I build a NAS/Cloud Storage network served from two or more synchronized servers?

Tags: file-management, networking, file-synchronization, cloud-storage

Standard problem: ~60 TB of data I would like to access from multiple devices (Android, Linux, maybe Web) outside of my apartment. The bottleneck: a local ISP which can give me no better than 5 Mbps of Upload and 50 Mbps of Download bandwidth.

Solutions I've Considered

- Syncthing. Good experience using to sync Music, Camera, and Essential Documents. Lacks selective sync or file “streaming.”
- Nextcloud. Single-point-of-Failure; bottle-necked by home upload bandwidth.
- NAS. Same problems as Nextcloud.

What I think *could* solve this problem is placing a second server outside of my apartment. I have two suitable locations (both with 100 Mbps symmetrical connections): an office cubical, my parent's home. This would also give an off-site backup. However, both of the networks are managed, meaning I have ZERO administrative access. I know that Syncthing will work from both networks. However, it does not solve the problem of accessing from these boxes, and not my bandwidth-limited apartment box.

I need a storage network solution which can “serve” files from two geographically separated and synchronized servers, to “clients”, in a manner that can function on networks which I cannot control.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! It seems you are rather looking for a strategy than for software. There's not much software can do about your available bandwidth – even if we knew what OS it must run on, how much it may cost etc (details we require for giving software recommendations). Can you please clarify?

Comment: @Izzy, I re-worded the question to reflect the sort of solution I had in mind, but do not know the software-side details of implementation.

Comment: Thanks Jake! That already helps a lot. I'd read the focus now that you want a software running in those two locations (server-part) and matching clients for your laptops/Smartphones. I'd call that asking for a software recommendation – and give it a +1 now as it seems pretty clear and well detailed. Good luck!